# Вызов неопределенного количества функций

Tags: javascript, promise, асинхронность

Доброго всем времени суток cтолкнулся с таким вопросом - создать функцию в которой первый параметр временной интервал (в секундах), а следующие параметры (неопределенное количество) будут являться функциями. Все эти функции должны запускаться одна за другой через временной интервал.

```
timer(2, () => result = 15, () => result = 80)
testing.tick(1000);
    assert(result).toBe(undefined);
    testing.tick(1000); 
    assert(result).toBe(15);
    testing.tick(1000); 
    assert(result).toBe(15);
    testing.tick(1000); 
    assert(result).toBe(8509);
```

Я пока учусь, но у меня есть предположение, что это реализовывается через Promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function runAll(delay) {
  var funcs = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++)
    funcs.push(arguments[i]);
  var index = 0;
  function runOne() {
    funcs[index]();
    if (++index < funcs.length)
      setTimeout(runOne, delay);
  }
  if (funcs.length)
    setTimeout(runOne, delay);
}

runAll(1000, 
  function(){console.log("One");},
  function(){console.log("Two");},
  function(){console.log("Three");}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const ВРЕМЯ_ОЖИДАНИЯ = 1000;

function подождать_и_сделать(ВРЕМЯ_ОЖИДАНИЯ, ...очередь_дел) {
  setTimeout(wait_a_minute, ВРЕМЯ_ОЖИДАНИЯ);

  function wait_a_minute() {
    очередь_дел.forEach(сделать_дельце);

    function сделать_дельце(дельце) {
      дельце();
    }
  }
}

function сделать_так() {
  console.log('делаю так')
}

function сделать_этак() {
  console.log('делаю этак');
}

подождать_и_сделать(ВРЕМЯ_ОЖИДАНИЯ, сделать_так, сделать_этак);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function runAll(delay, ...list) {
  list.forEach((x,i) => setTimeout(x, delay*(i+1)))
}

runAll(1000, 
  function(){console.log("One");},
  function(){console.log("Two");},
  function(){console.log("Three");}
);
```